Is there a simple way to create a plane that perfectly aligns with another plane that is rotated by x degree but twist back to be flat?
I'm a total noob with Blender, and I guess it can't be that hard, but I can't get it done. So, I have two copies of the same object, and what I want to achieve is that one is rotated by a given degree x (around one axis), and I want the other to perfectly align with it and then "twist" to be parallel to the "ground".



You can make an object follow a curve with the Curve Modifier. The points in curve can be tilted with Ctrl+T to twist the object. Also move the control points so it connects to the other object
